# TimeoutException on telegram java client

Tags: java, timeout, telegram

i used the java telegram api to communicate with telegram core api in windows intellij idea 
https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api

But the app is facing Timeout error in line 
`TLConfig config = api.doRpcCall(new TLRequestHelpGetConfig());`
Full source code:

```
AppInfo appinfo=new AppInfo(45687, "Myapp", "154", "587","en");
    TLRequestAuthCheckPhone checkRequest = new TLRequestAuthCheckPhone("96521452365");


    MyApiStorage state=new MyApiStorage();
    TelegramApi api = new TelegramApi(state, appinfo, new ApiCallback()
    {
        public void onApiDies(TelegramApi api) {
            // When auth key or user authorization dies
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpdatesInvalidated(TelegramApi api) {
            System.out.print("############################### onUpdatesInvalidated");
            // When api engine expects that update sequence might be broken
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthCancelled(TelegramApi ta) {
            System.out.print("############################### onAuthCancelled");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(TLAbsUpdates updates) {
            System.out.print("############################### onUpdate");
            System.out.println("user Id ::::"+((TLUpdateShortMessage) updates).getFromId());

        }
    });
    api.switchToDc(1);
    TLConfig config = api.doRpcCall(new TLRequestHelpGetConfig());
    System.out.print("############################### config" + config.getTestMode());
    state.updateSettings(config);
    api.doRpcCall(checkRequest, new RpcCallbackEx<TLCheckedPhone>() {
        public void onConfirmed() {
            System.out.print("############################### onConfirmed");
        }

        public void onResult(TLCheckedPhone result) {
            boolean invited = result.getPhoneInvited();
            boolean registered = result.getPhoneRegistered();
            System.out.print("############################### onResult" + registered);
            // TODO process response further
        }

        public void onError(int errorCode, String message) {
            System.out.print("############################### onError" + message);
        }
    });
```

can someone help me

Answer (score 2):

Your timeout might happen for several reasons:
1. You are using

```
    api.doRpcCall(new TLRequestHelpGetConfig());
```

In the TelegramApi class this translates into

```
    return this.doRpcCall(method, timeout, 0);
```

0 there stands for DC. If your DC is different you will timeout
2. There were suggestions in other places to use doRpcCallSide instead and it worked for some and not for others. The reason is it translates into

```
    return this.doRpcCall(method, 15000, this.primaryDc, true);
```

where true stands authRequired.
 
3. If you want to do this without authorization then use

```
api.doRpcCallNonAuth
```